# Creating Random Array in order to time Sorting Algorithms

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I saw an article where they were timing the classic sorting algorithms to see which one was fastest and by how much.  I wanted to replicate that process.  I think all my sorting algorithms are correct but I'm having trouble creating a random array.

Here's my main method which calls the other class and sends them the random array.

```
public class Timer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numArray;
    InsertionSort insert = new InsertionSort();
    MergeSort merge = new MergeSort();
    QuickSort quick = new QuickSort();
    SelectionSort select = new SelectionSort();
    BubbleSort bubble = new BubbleSort();
    int sizeNumber = 0;
    Scanner scanner;
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter size of arrayList to be sorted: ");
    sizeNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();
    numArray = new int[sizeNumber];
    arraySize(sizeNumber, numArray);
    insert.sort(numArray);
    merge.sort(numArray);
    quick.sort(numArray);
    select.sort(numArray);
    bubble.sort(numArray);

}

public static int[] arraySize(int number, int[] array) {

    Random rng = new Random();

    array = new int[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int random = rng.nextInt();
        array[i] = random;

    }
    return array;
}

}
```

For the purpose of clarity, I'm asking how to create an int[] array and fill it with random numbers at a length of the user's choice.  Currently, the method I'm using returns a value similar to `[I@9931f5` instead of any numbers.

Comment: What sort of problem are you having?

Comment: Micro-benchmarking Java algorithms is one of the most complex tasks to solve. Don't do it. If you do it, then use a tool that tries to avoid all the pitfalls of incorrect benchmarks, like Caliper. Also, you should choose: either the badly named arraySize() method modifies its argument, or it returns a (new) array. Making both is extremely confusing. The Java way of doing is to make it create and return an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
array[i] = array[random];
```

This isn't what you want. `random` can be any legal `int` value so you're likely to go out of bounds. I believe you'd want

```
array[i] = random;
```

instead.

You're also allocating an unnecessary array in there (`new int[...]` right before overwriting it in `arraySize`), and you don't really need to return a value from `arraySize` (although using a return value instead of an output parameter would be cleaner).

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you confine the numbers that generated from Random.nextInt, so that the numbers won't go too large and too diverse.

And so with minor fixes, your arraySize function can work properly like this:

```
public static void arraySize(int[] array) {

   Random rng = new Random();

   for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    array[i]=rng.nextInt(100); 
   /*here I fix the size to 0 - 100, you can create a way 
     to adjust this with respect to the array size as well,
     so that the numbers could distribute more evenly */
   }
}
```

Since you're passing the array to the function, there is no need to return it.

Secondly, the num array is passed as reference to each sorting:

```
insert.sort(numArray);
merge.sort(numArray);
quick.sort(numArray);
select.sort(numArray);
bubble.sort(numArray);
```

The numArray will be sorted by the first insert.sort, so the second and following sort will simply get a sorted numArray, it doesn't successfully test the sorting complexity. You have to manually obtain multiple copies of the numArray to serve as the arguments for each sorting, a simple function can do that:

```
 public static void copyArray(int[] copy,int[] array){
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        copy[i]=array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I had thought of your second point.  I put a few lines in each class like this in attempt to keep the original array unsorted. `public void sort(int[] array) {
    int[] array2 = new int[array.length];
    array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);`

Comment: I tried using the code you gave me for the random number array, and every time I run it I get `[I@df8f5e` when I syso the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] randomArray(int size, int lower, int higher)
{
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = r.nextInt(higher-lower) + lower;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

This will generate an array of size `size`, of values between `lower` and `higher`